# How to Write a Visual Studio Macro Event to get user's typed Code?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, macros, visual-studio-macros

i'm looking for a way to write a macro event to parse user's code.
for example when programmer writes some specific code this event will parse the code line and if matches a regular expression will insert some additional codes on active document.
how can i get hole line code and which event should i use?

Answer (score 2):

You can use TextDocumentKeyPressEvents.AfterKeyPress event. The following macro triggers after user presses any key in text editor. Then it gets the current line. This example tests, if the line contains "hello" text and if so, it shows the line in message box.

```
Private Sub TextDocumentKeyPressEvents_AfterKeyPress(ByVal Keypress As String, _
ByVal Selection As EnvDTE.TextSelection, ByVal InStatementCompletion As Boolean) _
Handles TextDocumentKeyPressEvents.AfterKeyPress
    Try
        Dim line As String

        Dim aPoint As EditPoint = Selection.ActivePoint.CreateEditPoint
        Dim startPoint As EditPoint = aPoint.CreateEditPoint
        startPoint.StartOfLine()
        Dim endPoint As EditPoint = aPoint.CreateEditPoint
        endPoint.EndOfLine()
        line = startPoint.GetText(endPoint)

        If line.Contains("hello") Then
            MsgBox(line)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

To create and apply this macro:

1. Go to menu Tools - Macros - Macros IDE...
2. In the Macros IDE Class View navigate to MyMacros - {}
       MyMacros - EnvironmentEvents. Open (double-click) EnvironmentEvents.
3. Paste this code inside module (just before End Module line)

Answer (score -1):

There are events that Macros can respond to, however, I do not believe that text entry is one of them, a better approach might be to use snippets - [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165392%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)

They will allow you to define a keyword and then add text into the editor.
A good example is the property snippet; In your editor type 'prop' and then press Tab (twice in C#, once in VB) to invoke.

Here is more detailed list of available snippets:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat(v=VS.100).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z41h7fat%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)